# what is the another solution of getting the log of my data-set?

Tags: python

i am trying to get the log of my data to create a model, but there are a zero value in some rows, so the output of log(0) is -inf, which is leading a problem.

**if there are a better solution of deleting all zeros values?**

***my data set is :***

```
              ds    y
    0   2020-01-22  0
    1   2020-01-23  0
    2   2020-01-24  0
    3   2020-01-25  0
    4   2020-01-26  0
    ... ... ...
    353 2021-01-09  148799
    354 2021-01-10  149792
    355 2021-01-11  150753
    356 2021-01-12  151723
    357 2021-01-13  152719
```

Comment: find the log by excluding zeros. you can do it by using `df[df.y != 0]`

Comment: It's hard to say what to do without seeing your code, but you should just either do a `try-except` or just filter out all `inf` values.

Answer (score 1):

You can use list comprehension:

```
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np
a = pd.DataFrame({'y':[0,7,67656,15,0,2]})
print(a)

a["log"] = np.log10(a["y"])

a["log"] = [x[1] if x[0]!=0 else 0 for x in a.to_numpy()]
```

Or even easier:

```
import math
a["log"] = [math.log10(x) if x!=0 else 0 for x in a["y"]]
```

Put whatever you need after else.

Comment: It'll ignore all the `0` value exist in the data, which may not be a suitable option if the data consists of hundreds/thousands if not millions of `0's`, as those could be required for data analysis, modeling (or other) purpose.

Comment: It will not, it will replace -inf with chosen value, in my case string, but of course OP can replace that with for example -100, whatever value fits his needs. It is similar approach to yours where you add/substract a constant to all values, your approach has a small problem if the value +/- constant will result in 0. Might not happen in this case but still there is such possibility.

Comment: Yeah, there exists some probability of that (very unlikely looking at the questioner's data), also rounding proneness of packages and libraries could also turn them to zero thus I've added a note at the very end.

Comment: I better replaced the strings with 0

Answer (score 0):

*It's a simple workaround for your problem, there may exist a more sophisticated way of doing it.*

You could simply take `log(x+a)` instead of `log(x)` where `a` is a chosen constant (or hyperparameter you could say in ML lingo) and the value of a could be a very small number (for example `0.00001`) depending on your aim and tolerance. So now you would calculate `log(0+0.00001)` instead of `log(0)` and it'll give a value `-5` instead of blowing up.

As I said, there could be possibilities of a more smart way of going about it such as understanding the data thoroughly, why `0` exists there in the first place, what do they represent, etc.

(*Note: It (value of `a`) shouldn't be however very low/small number, as all packages/software have a level of rounding, so it may round up and turn your `a` to zero.)*

Answer (score 0):

You may like to use [`numpy.log`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.log.html) with the "where" parameter:

```
df['y'] =  np.log(df['y'], where = df['y'] != 0)
```

You can also do it the following way:

```
mask = df['y'] != 0
valid = df.loc[mask,'y']
df['y'] = 0

df.loc[mask, 'y'] = np.log(valid)
```